# jquery change variable function not working

Tags: jquery

Here is a sample of my code, i've removed the unnecessary parts.  I've set a global variable `recipient`.  It should be alert `1` but nothing is being alerted.  What is the correct way to change a variable set outside a function?  How do i solve this?

```
var recipient = 0;

$("#submit-button").click(function () {

    $.getJSON("/fetch.php?o=4&user=" + k, function (B) {
        $.each(B, function (index, result) {
            recipient = 1;

        })

    })

    if (recipient == 1) {
        alert("yes");
    }
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to asyn call, put the condition in callback function instead of putting if after it. The call back is called after the click function finished execution.

```
var recipient = 0;      


$("#submit-button").click(function() {

  $.getJSON("/fetch.php?o=4&user=" + k, function(B) {
       $.each(B, function(index, result) {
            recipient = 1;    
       });
      if(recipient==1) {
         alert("yes");
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking to see if recipient is 1 before the JSON request is complete. Add it inside the callback function.

```
var recipient = 0;

$("#submit-button").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/fetch.php?o=4&user=" + k, function (B) {
        $.each(B, function (index, result) {
            recipient = 1;
        });

        if (recipient == 1) {
            alert("yes");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a way to  make sure JSON request is complete, so i don't have to have it in the callback function?